# How to know the caller/parent ActionResult when RedirectToAction is used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having the following code:

```
     public ActionResult EditTrain(EditTraing editrain)
     {
      ....
      ....
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = "200241"}); 
     }
```

Once I am in the Details Action, I like to check who the referrer was. In this case, I would be the EditTrain. Is there anyway I can figure out what Action the Redirection came from?

Comment: you may pass info in query string, as another parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use TempData or pass the information in the redirect itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably send some keys in the `querystring`

```
 public ActionResult EditTrain(EditTraing editrain)
 {     
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = "200241" ,from="edittrain"}); 
 }
 public ActionResult Details(int id,string from)
 {
      //do stuff        
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From memory you should be able to access HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer from within your action.